# After disabling console appender in log4j still getting info message in catalina.out

Tags: java, log4j

I initialize root logger with level `ALL` for R.

```
log4j.rootLogger=ALL, R
log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p (%F:%L) - %m%n

log4j.appender.R.File=${catalina.home}/logs/synconextcontroller.log
log4j.appender.R.DatePattern='-'yyyyMMdd'.log'
log4j.appender.R.Threshold=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.catalina=DEBUG, R
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.quartz=ERROR
log4j.logger.com.mchange=ERROR
jersey.level=INFO
```

Despite this, logs are getting written to file.

How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Did you restart tomcat?

Comment: @MichaelMarkidis Yes